# Difference between single and multiple .pipe

Tags: rxjs, observable, reactive, rxjs-observables

I was composing an observable stream with this intent:
having an observable emitting from a web request and 2 triggers, one for re-emitting the value obtained and the other trigger to re-load the value (re-executing the request). Also, late subscribers should get the last value obtained and be able to receive reset/reload.

Initially I ended up with the following code (which didn't work):

```js
public readonly initialValueFlat$ = this.seed$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(seed => defer(
      () => {
        this._isLoading$$.next(true);
        return this.getFakeData(seed)
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => this._isLoading$$.next(false)));
      })),
    repeatWhen(x => this._reloadTrigger$),
    switchMap(x => of(x)),
    repeatWhen(x => this._resetTrigger$),
    shareReplay(1));
```

working on it I found the following solution:

```js
public readonly initialValue$ = this.seed$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(seed => defer(
      () => {
        this._isLoading$$.next(true);
        return this.getFakeData(seed)
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => this._isLoading$$.next(false)));
      })
      .pipe(
        repeatWhen(x => this._reloadTrigger$))
      .pipe(
        switchMap(x =>
          of(x)
            .pipe(
              repeatWhen(x => this._resetTrigger$))))),
    shareReplay(1));
```

But it is not fully clear to me why the first one doesn't work, and how is the multiple `.pipe` operators affect the chain.
Can you help me make it clear?
Thanks

Comment: The two chains are different. In the second one, `repeatWhen` is used inside `switchMap` while in the first one it's used outside that will definitelly produce different behavior. However, I don't know what behavior you're expecting so I can't tell which one is corrext.

Comment: well, it doesn't matter much what the intent is, it's the structure that counts and sets the difference, anyways I updated the post with the info you asked

Comment: The two chains are still different, so I wouldn’t expect the same bahavior :).

Comment: in fact the question is: which characteristic of the pipe operator makes them different? :)

Comment: The difference is not in using `pipe()`, you have two differently structured chains (different nesting). That's why you're seeing different behavior. It's not because you're using `pipe()` multiple times.

Comment: can you elaborate on what happens in the first and in the second?

Comment: It's specifically the pipe that comes after `of(x)` that needs to stay, because the `switchMap` is using the resulting observable of what's inside of it.

Comment: @Sergio I mentined what's different in my first comment.

Comment: @ShamPooSham tank you for your reply, I just don't understand why i can't let it flow like in the first example, what does the pipe do that is important to be placed right there?

Comment: @Sergio The difference is because of how switchMap works. switchMap will cancel the previous subscription to the inner observable (the one inside the switchMap function) when a new value is emitted from the outer observable (what comes "into" it). In one case, you only cancel `of(x)`. In the other case, you cancel `of(x)` piped into the `repeatWhen`.

Comment: so `repeatWhen` refers to source observable on which `.pipe` is attached, even though `repeatWhen` there are other operators between it and `.pipe(` start?

Comment: Yes, something like that. pipe is a property function on an observable, it is unaware of other pipes surrounding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## About Pipe

Pipe doesn't do anything on it's own. It just composes operators for you. The following are all the same:

```ts
of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(
  take(3),
  map(v => v + 1),
  filter(v => v != 3)
);

of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(
  take(3),
).pipe(
  map(v => v + 1),
  filter(v => v != 3)
);

of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(
  take(3),
  map(v => v + 1)
).pipe(
  filter(v => v != 3)
);

of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe(
  take(3)
).pipe(
  map(v => v + 1)
).pipe(
  filter(v => v != 3)
);

of(1,2,3,4,5).pipe().pipe().pipe().pipe().pipe(
  take(3),
  map(v => v + 1),
  filter(v => v != 3)
).pipe().pipe().pipe().pipe().pipe().pipe().pipe();
```

## Your code

I've commented your code with what's happening at each step.

Hopefully that can give you some idea of why the two observables are very different.

There's not much else I can do since it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

#### Commenting initialValueFlat$

```ts
const initialValueFlat$ = this.seed$.pipe(

  // SwitchMap subscribes to seed$ as source, then creates
  // a new getFakeData stream for each emission, cancelling old streams
  // (The defer you had here does nothing so I've removed)
  switchMap(seed => {
    this._isLoading$$.next(true);
    return this.getFakeData(seed).pipe(
      finalize(() => this._isLoading$$.next(false))
    );
  }),

  // Once the switchMap completes, resubscribes to the switchmap when
  // reloadTrigger$ emits. SwitchMap will resubscribe to seed$
  repeatWhen(_ => this._reloadTrigger$),

  // Creates a new observable that's identical to the source observable.
  // Soooo, this wastes CPU cycles and does nothing.
  switchMap(x => of(x)),

  // Same as the last one since the swtichmap between the two is 
  // effectively a no-op
  repeatWhen(_ => this._resetTrigger$),

  // Make this observable hot and let subscribers share values
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

#### Commenting initialValue$

```ts
const initialValue$ = this.seed$.pipe(

  // SwitchMap subscribes to seed$ as source, then creates
  // a new getFakeData stream for each emission, cancelling old streams.
  switchMap(seed => 
    // It's defer that gets repeated, so unlike the previous code, if
    // you want isLoading$$.next to fire on each repeat, you do need defer
    defer(() => { 
      this._isLoading$$.next(true);
      return this.getFakeData(seed).pipe(
        finalize(() => this._isLoading$$.next(false)),
      );
    }).pipe(
      // Once defer completes, this will resubscribe to defer when 
      // reloadTrigger$ emits. This doesn't resubscribe to seed$, it
      // will end up calling getFakeData(seed) again.
      repeatWhen(_ => this._reloadTrigger$),

      switchMap(x => of(x).pipe(
        // Once the source completes (which is always going to happen 
        // immediately after x is emitted), this will emit x every time
        // reloadTrigger$ emits.
        repeatWhen(_ => this._reloadTrigger$)
      ))
    )
  ),

  // Make this observable hot and let subscribers share values
  shareReplay(1)
);
```